# @ISA vs use base vs use parent

Tags: perl

Ran across this little nugget... I think I have it figured out, but see if anyone can shed more light.

I have a module in my `PERL5LIB` environment variable that I use for logging.  It is in `e:/Scripts/Log/Logger.pm`. Following is an excerpt:

```
package Log::Logger;
...

package Log::NullLogger;
use base 'Log::Logger';
...

package Log::FileLogger;
use base 'Log::Logger';
...

package Log::DateFileLogger;
use base 'Log::FileLogger';
...

package LogTester;
use Data::Dump 'dump';
test() unless caller();
sub test {
    warn dump \%INC;
    ...
}
```

I wanted to make some changes to this module so I copied it to `e:/Test/Log/Log/Logger.pm` and started making changes and testing... I added a new class and altered an inherited routine in the `Log::Logger` package...

```
package BasicFormatter;
...
```

But my tests were very odd.  Some of the new code was being used, some was not.  The dump of `%INC` had:

```
"Log/Logger.pm" => "e:/Scripts/Log/Logger.pm"
```

... the *old module*!  From what I can tell, `use base 'Log::Logger'` went out and re-loaded `Log/Logger.pm` from `PERL5LIB`, replacing only those packages in it (i.e. `package BasicFormatter` was coming from the new module, but all other packages were from the old module).

I read about `use parent` and when I replaced my `use base` with `use parent` I got compile errors on `use parent 'Log::FileLogger'` ostensibly because there was no `Log/FileLogger.pm` module.  `use base` never complained about this -- a weakness in `use parent` in my opinion.

I added

```
use lib '..';
```

to the top of the module and everything worked with `use base` but that was not a fix I like, because it would not be in the final module when I "publish" it back to `e:/Scripts/Log/Logger.pm`.  With the `use lib '..'`, `%INC` now showed

```
"Log/Logger.pm" => "../Log/Logger.pm"
```

which makes sense.

My next step was to remove the `use lib '..'` and replace all `use base...` with `our @ISA=(...)`.  When I did this, the code started working and `%INC` didn't show an entry for `Log/Logger.pm` at all.

Note, when I set up a test script in `e:/Test/Log/TestLogger.pl` with

```
use lib '.';
```

in it, it picks up `e:/Test/Log/Log/Logger.pm` fine and the `use base` calls don't re-require the package.

So, my conclusion is this... when running the module as a modulino, the module isn't "loaded" as far as Perl is concerned.  So the first attempt to `use base` on that module does a `require <module>` which then loads it from the `@INC` path, which could replace packages already in the modulino being executed.  Using `@ISA` instead bypasses the calls to `require` and so the module isn't loaded from `@INC`.

Anyone else got more information on this... is testing a module as a modulino just a bad idea?

Comment: For `use parent` when the class code is loaded from a different file, see its `-norequire` option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`parent` requires you to explicitly say whether you want it to actually load the parent module or just set up inheritance.  This is a strength, not a weakness; `base` had the weakness of always *trying* to load the module, leading to the problem you had.

Do:

```
use parent -norequire => 'Log::Logger';
...
use parent -norequire => 'Log::FileLogger';
```

etc.

That said, the problem `base` had wouldn't have happened if you consistently used `use` or `require` to load your module; if you just run a module (e.g. `perl Foo/Bar.pm`) or otherwise load it (`use Test::Log::Logger` instead of `use lib 'Test'; use Log::Logger`??) and your code also tries to `use` it, you always risk multiple versions being found.

Comment: I found this looking for multiple-inheritance, so FYI in case someone else is looking too.  Just call `use parent foo` multiple times for each parent.  I believe perl will depth-first search the parent hierarchy in order looking for the first matching function name.

Comment: @KJ7LNW yes, multiple `use parent`s will add multiple things to @INC in that order, and depth-first is the default but can be changed with [mro](http://p3rl.org/mro)

Answer (score 10):

I think it would be useful to clarify a few things:

### [`@ISA`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#@ISA)

is for defining a package's parent classes. It does not affect how packages are loaded. You can manipulate it directly, or you can use the [`parent`](http://perldoc.perl.org/parent.html) or the slightly older [`base`](http://perldoc.perl.org/base.html) pragmas. The difference between manipulating `@ISA` directly and these two pragmas is that the pragmas do a little more: `use base qw/Foo Bar/;` and `use parent qw/Foo Bar/;` are both roughly similar in effect to

```
BEGIN {
    require Foo;
    require Bar;
    push @ISA, qw(Foo Bar);
}
```

meaning that not only do they manipulate `@ISA`, they also load the package with [`require`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html). There is one exception, which is `use parent -norequire, qw/Foo Bar/;` - this may be useful if, as you seem to be showing, all of your packages reside in the same file. However, both pragmas do not affect how `require` operates, including where it looks, for that you need to manipulate `@INC`.

### [`@INC`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#@INC)

is the place that Perl's [`use`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html), [`require`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html), and [`do`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html) look for files (the latter with a few exceptions). There are several ways to manipulate `@INC`:

- From the command line: `perl -I/path/to/modules script.pl` (see [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html))
- From within each script individually: [`use lib '/path/to/modules';`](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html), or by direct manipulation of `@INC`
- Using the [`PERL5LIB`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#PERL5LIB) environment variable
- Globally for the Perl installation: [`sitecustomize.pl`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#%2A-f%2A) (only when [configured](https://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/60dfa515ef5:/INSTALL#l774))
- When building a new Perl, there are [various options](https://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob/60dfa515ef5:/INSTALL) (search for "@INC")

Perl looks through `@INC` in order. So in your case, if Perl is loading the wrong version of `Log::Logger`, that means that Perl finds it earlier in `@INC` than the version you actually wanted to load. I would recommend inspecting `@INC` and making sure that you only include those paths from which you actually want to load modules, or placing the path for the "development" version of `Log::Logger` earlier in `@INC`. For example, when I develop modules, I usually specify the directory for the development version on the command line with e.g. `perl -Ilib ...`.

Note that there was a change as of Perl 5.26: [the current directory `.` was removed as a default entry in `@INC`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5260delta.html#Removal-of-the-current-directory-(".")-from-@INC). (Perl 5.24.1 [also introduced](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5241delta.html#Core-modules-and-tools-no-longer-search-_"."_-for-optional-modules) some related changes.)

### [`%INC`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%INC)

basically just keeps track of which modules have already been loaded, so that `require` and `use` don't load the same module twice. While it is possible to trick `require` into not looking for a file by adding its entry to `%INC` manually, there are usually better solutions than this.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you place each module in a separate file. To inline a module such that you can use `use Module`, you get the best results by replacing

```
use Log::Logger;
```

with

```
BEGIN {
   package Log::Logger;
   ...

   $INC{"Log/Logger.pm"} = 1;
}

BEGIN { import Log::Logger; }
```

Then, future use of `use Log::Logger;` (including `use base 'Log::Logger';` and `use parent 'Log::Logger';`) will work properly, including exporting.

In this particular case, @ysth's solution is adequate. I recommend moving away from base.pm in any case.